# Способы создания внешнего ключа в phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, структуры-данных, индексы

Нашел в интернете 2 способа создания внешнего ключа - [Первый способ](https://kb.justhost.ru/article/1635) и [Второй способ](https://folkprog.net/sozdanie-svyazey-phpmyadmin/).

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что оба способа с физической точки зрения приводят к одному и тому же результату? (формируется один и тот же sql запрос)
2. Какой их этих способов лучше?

Comment: быстрее руками запрос написать, чем тыкать там кучу кнопок

Comment: *Нашел в интернете 2 способа создания внешнего ключа* Вы невнимательны. Эти ссылки суммарно описывают ТРИ способа.